# How to fix no telemety data (e.g. Events, Exceptions) in Azure Application Live Metric Stream?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, metrics

I've a C# client witch i want to monitor with azure insights.

I've added the following Nugets:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights v2.9.1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept v2.4.0
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector v2.9.1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector v2.9.1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web v2.9.1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer v2.9.1
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel v2.9.1
Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation v1.0.5
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource v4.5.1
```

The problem is that the Azure Portal is recognizing my events and exceptions in the usage category but not as live metric stream. My Client is connected and the live metric stream is available but no temeletry data like tracked events or exceptions are shown. Even in Visual Studio there is no available Application Insights data during the debugging time.

I've tried a lot of times to uninstall and reinstall all the nugets. Updated them to the newest version but without any effort.

This is the related code for my Azure Client. The Payload is just a class with a few properties witch i want to track. It's mapped into a dictionary for the payload to send.

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        base.Initialize();

        var configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration();
        configuration.InstrumentationKey = Configuration.AnalyticsCodeId;

        var dependencies = new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule();
        dependencies.Initialize(configuration);

        configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
        configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer());
        configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AccountIdTelemetryInitializer());
        customTelemetry = new AzureCustomTelemetryInitializer(Payload);
        configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(customTelemetry);

        client = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

        if (CheckTrackingIsAllowed())
            InitLiveMetric(configuration);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Write(e);
    }
}

private void InitLiveMetric(TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
{
    QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor processor = null;

    configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
        .Use((next) =>
        {
            processor = new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next);
            return processor;
        })
        .Build();

    var quickPulse = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();
    quickPulse.Initialize(configuration);
    quickPulse.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(processor);
}

public override void SendEventAsync(string eventName, string modulName)
{
    if (!CheckTrackingIsAllowed())
        return;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var p = MapAzurePayload(Payload);
        client.TrackEvent(eventName, p);
    });
}
```

This code seems to work properly as i can see the the tracked events and exceptions in the usage category in the Azure Portal. But as i said, not as live metric what would be very nice and must normally work with the code i think.

Any ideas why the live metric stream is not working as intended?

Edit: Found the reason... The problem is that my first track event is send when the client seems not to be ready at all. If I delayed the sending it works as intended. 
My solution is to delay the first sending of a track. Not nice but i have no other idea...

Comment: Have you added instrumentationKey in your appSettings and configured to use those in startup?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the initialize method. I would assume otherwise the Azure Portal would not react on my running client.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your Live Metrics blade in the portal please?

Comment: Can you check whether these instruction work (no need to setup auth api key for now)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream#classic-aspnet

Comment: @tokaplan what do you mean with Metrics blade?

Comment: @ZakiMa these setting works. But live Metrics is working with my settings as well. The problem is that i can't see live events and exceptions.

Comment: Got it. Can you please paste the screenshot of what you see in live metrics? Is it just only metrics / servers parts populated and events/exceptions are empty?

Comment: @ZakiMa i have the solution. I've edited my request. The client is not ready when sending the first request. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Great that solution worked! @Christoph, it doesn't sound right that you need to delay anything to make Live Metrics to work. If you can create a github issue, post a code which works and which doesn't - this would greatly help. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server

Comment: Or we can continue here. Though in SO it might be trickier.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have a git hub account. But the code in my first post is still the same. The only different for the working version is a Thread.Sleep(5000) before client.TrackEvent